# Why is my Vim crashing on one particular Ruby file?

Tags: ruby, vim

The output I'm seeing is,

```
Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV3C

Vim: Finished.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This happens only when I try to open one particular Ruby source file. Other Ruby source files open just fine, but this one particular one does not.

Comment: You might want to attach the file / submit debug information to VIM team, you probably won't get constructive answers with just this info

Comment: You can also bisext the code in that file to narrow down the possible causes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there were some strange invisible characters in the file. I tried to remove them with a `tr` command that removes non-ASCII characters, but that didn't work.

So, I just kind of copied lines over manually to a new file, hoping to exclude the strange characters that were causing the issue, and that seemed to work.

Comment: If you're able, share the file that caused the segfault. Better to fix this in vim if it's really a bug!